# Rolling back changes to a table without PK

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I have a table defined as follows WITHOUT PK (primary key)

```
Code   Value
  A     X
  A     Y
  A     Z
  B     F
  C     Q
```

I run an update as follows

```
  update MY_TABLE set VALUE = 'F' where Code='A';
  commit;
```

So, the table becomes

```
 Code    Value
  A        F
  A        F
  A        F
  B        F
  C        Q
```

Now my requirement is to "rollback" the update programmatically, so that the table data is restored as it was before the change.

I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish this, without creating a backup table ?

Comment: Search for flashback query in oracle documentation.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for the undo management in oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/undo.htm#i1008645

Comment: Note that I want to do it "programmatically" and not use backup table, flashback, backup, archive logs etc.

Comment: Somewhere you have to keep the data, where you want to revert to, either in the code or in the database.

Comment: @Myonara - I want to do this using straight SQL. Besides - how will UNDO help ?

Comment: COMMIT commits... Check out different transaction modes.

Comment: @jarlh - now sure what you mean. I have already COMMITed the transaction. Now I realize that I made a mistake and want to undo my changes.

Comment: I see, it's already done... Well, kindly ask a DBA to restore a back-up.

Comment: My requirement is to be able to do this "programmatically" , which means using SQL. No backup, flashback, temporary tables, archive logs etc.

Comment: You say you made a mistake and want to undo your changes. Then there are some requirements - stated by who?

Comment: If you know what the data should be, you can write a query that does the update. If not, you won't be able to do it without needing something like a database restore, flashback, etc. Unless your UNDO retention is big enough that you could use `select ... from <your_table> as of timestamp (<timestamp>)`

Comment: @jarlh - the requirement are defined by business need. Imagine we have made these changes to a production database and after sometimes we realize that we have made a mistake. Trying to restore the data from backup seems to be an overkill, especially given how small the change is.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you know the values that are to be restored.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( Code, Value ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'Z' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'Q' FROM DUAL;

update MY_TABLE set VALUE = 'F' where Code='A';
```

**Merge Statement**:

```sql
MERGE INTO my_table dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  Code = 'A'
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET VALUE = DECODE( src.rn, 1, 'X', 2, 'Y', 3, 'Z', dst.value );
```

or, a slightly more generic solution:

```sql
MERGE INTO my_table dst
USING (
  WITH data_to_restore (code, value ) AS (
    SELECT 'A', 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 'Z' FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT t.rid,
         d.value
  FROM   (
    SELECT Code,
           ROWID AS rid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
    FROM   my_table
  ) t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT d.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
    FROM   data_to_restore d 
  ) d
  ON ( t.code = d.code AND t.rn = d.rn )

) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET VALUE = src.value;
```

**Output**:

After either merge statement then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

outputs:

> ```
> CODE | VALUE
> :--- | :----
> A    | X    
> A    | Y    
> A    | Z    
> B    | F    
> C    | Q
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=84dcaa603dcd4bed86f3da683db65243)*

Comment: this is probably closest answer, but requires that we know the values beforehand. Also if the number of values increase the "DECODE ( src.rn ..... ) " will become very long

Comment: @oradbanj If you don't know the values then you need to restore from backups or use flashback. As for the second part, I added a second `MERGE` statement (before you made that comment) where you can put the data in a `SELECT` statement and `DECODE` is no longer used.

Comment: your second MERGE statement is great. But that still requires that I examine the data before writing the statement. What I am trying to get to is that there is no easy way to accomplish this without saving the entire table or at least rows I am modifying somewhere and restore it. Am I correct ?

Comment: @oradbanj Enable flashback if you want to restore a table to a previous state. But if you don't know what the data is (and aren't using flashback) then there is not a way you can do it programmatically.